# Find the distribution of random variable using specific method.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be the random variable with distribution $X \in \mathcal{E}(1) $, find the distributions of the following random variables:

a) $Y=X^2$

b) $Y=\lfloor X \rfloor$

$f_X(x)= e^{-x}, x\geq 0$

NOTE: The only method i am allowed to use here (not sure if there's a name for that method) is the method that consists of drawing a graph of function and then placing few characteristic lines on graph parallel to the $X$-axis, and then calculating the integral between the points where line and graph intersect

For example:
[image]

Now, integrating from $-\sqrt{2} $ to $\sqrt{2}$ gives us the distribution function for $Y$.

I would like an intuitive explanation on why this works and how could i find density of $Y$ when i have this. Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is the usual CDF method. If $Y=g(X)$, then distribution function of $Y$ is

$$P(Y\le y)=P(g(X)\le y)=P(X\in A)\,,\quad A=\{x:g(x)\le y\}$$

Using graph, you are finding the region $A$.

Comment: Oh, i see, thanks, but how could i find density function when i have this?

Comment: By differentiating the distribution function, you would get the density function, provided $Y$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: @StubbornAtom That works because differentiation is opposite of integration in a way, i think i got that, what about the second case b) , as far as i can see that is not continuous distribution, how am i supposed to act in that kind of situations, will it's distribution also be discrete?

Comment: The second one has a discrete distribution and you can find $P(Y=y)$ directly.

Comment: @StubbornAtom So in second case distribution would be $P(Y=k)=e^{-k}$, is that right?

Comment: No. $P(\lfloor X\rfloor=k)=P(k\le X<k+1)=\cdots$

Comment: @StubbornAtom I see, that's because every number up to k+1 will have the same result as k does, in this case, so it would be $P(Y=k)=e^{-k} - e^{-(k+1)}$. If your comments were answer, i would accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. You have $P(\lfloor X\rfloor =k)=(1-e^{-1})e^{-k}\mathbf1_{k\,\in\,\{0,1,2,\cdots\}}$. So $\lfloor X\rfloor$ has a geometric distribution with parameter $1-e^{-1}$. You are welcome to post your own answers and accept them.